# How to get a VisualBrush to fill its container in Xaml?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have textbox I am using for search, and I want to have hint text inside of it prompting the user to search as well as a magnifying glass icon.  I am using a `VisualBrush` style, and I want the label at the far left and the image at the far right, but I can't get the contents of the `VisualBrush` to fill the entire text box.  They are either stuck togethr at the left, or stuck together on the right, depending on how I set the `AlignmentX` on my `VisualBrush`.  I have tried using `StackPanel`, `DockPanel`, and `Grid` and none of them will fill the whole textbox and let me have elements at opposite ends of the text box.

```
<VisualBrush x:Key="CueBannerBrush"
             AlignmentX="Left"
             AlignmentY="Center"
             Stretch="None">
  <VisualBrush.Visual>
    <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
      <Label Content="Begin typing to search"
             Foreground="LightGray"
             DockPanel.Dock="Left" />
      <Image Source="/WPF;component/Icons/32/Modern3D/objects/magnifier.png"
             Height="20"
             DockPanel.Dock="Right" />
    </DockPanel>
  </VisualBrush.Visual>
</VisualBrush>
```

Produces this output:

[image]

Any suggestions for how I can get the child of the brush to fill the whole text box and separate the hint text from the magnifying glass icon?

Answer (score 4):

You could wrap it in a `Grid` instead and create the correct column sizes for each item (Label, Image)
Then you could bind the `VisualBrush` `width` to the `Texbox` `ActualWidth`.

```
<VisualBrush x:Key="CueBannerBrush"
             AlignmentX="Left"
             AlignmentY="Center"
             Stretch="None">
  <VisualBrush.Visual>
    <Grid Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=TextBox}}">
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="163*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="26" />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <Label Content="Begin typing to search"
             Foreground="LightGray"
             Grid.Column="0" />
      <Image Source="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/awicons/vista-artistic/24/search-icon.png"
             Height="20"
             Grid.Column="1" />
    </Grid>
  </VisualBrush.Visual>
</VisualBrush>
```

Result:

[image]